# Directional derivative of cost function under optimization. Finding bounds on decision variables.

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, matrix-calculus, inverse-problems, matrix-norms

Given the optimization problem

\begin{align}
  \boldsymbol{ x}^*,  \boldsymbol{y}^* &= \min_{ \boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{y}}( V( \boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{y}))\\
  s.t: \quad &  \boldsymbol{A x} +  \boldsymbol{I y }=  \boldsymbol{0}
 \end{align}
    where 
    \begin{align}
  V( \boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{y})=& g( \boldsymbol{x}) + g_y( \boldsymbol{y})\\
 g_y( \boldsymbol{y})=& \boldsymbol{y}^T  \boldsymbol{y}\\
 g( \boldsymbol{x})=& \sum_{i=1}^{n } g_i(x_i), \text{ for all } i \in \{1,\cdots, n\}
 \end{align}

with
    $  \boldsymbol{x} \in  \mathcal{R} ^{n \times 1}  $, $  \boldsymbol{y} \in  \mathcal{R} ^{m \times 1}  $, $  \boldsymbol{A} \in  \mathcal{R} ^{m \times n}  $ has full row-rank, $ m<n $ and $  \boldsymbol{I }\in  \mathcal{R} ^{m \times m}  $ is the identiy matrix, and the problem is strictly convex with one unique minimum (satisfying the KKT conditions).

Given we know an upper bound on $\nabla g_i(x_i) $:
\begin{align}
   |\nabla g_i(x_i^*) |& \le c  \text{ for all } i \in \{1,\cdots, n\}\\
   \implies  |\nabla_x g( \boldsymbol{x^*})|_{\infty}& \le c,
 \end{align}

can we limit  $ |\boldsymbol{y}^*|_{\infty} $?

---

My idea was to use that the directional derivative of $ V( \boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{y}) $, in direction $  \boldsymbol{d} $, at the solution (where $  \boldsymbol{d} $ is any feasible direction such that $\boldsymbol{Ax } +  \boldsymbol{I y }$ remains zero).
\begin{equation}\label{key}
 \boldsymbol{d} \cdot \nabla V( \boldsymbol{x}^*, \boldsymbol{y}^*) =  \boldsymbol{d} \cdot {\left[\begin{matrix}\nabla_x g( \boldsymbol{x}^*) \\ \nabla_y g( \boldsymbol{y}^*)  \end{matrix} \right]} =0
 \end{equation}
and then get a limit for $|\nabla g_y(\boldsymbol{y}) |$, which would give a limit on $|\boldsymbol{y}^*|_{\infty}$

But I did not manage to proceed, and am currently stuck. Any help or tips on how to proceed is welcome.

Comment: Since the constraint is linear, you can solve it to eliminate $y,\,$ i.e.
$$\eqalign{
V &= (-Ax)^T(-Ax) + g(x) \cr
 &= x^TA^TAx + g(x) \cr
}$$
Resulting in an unconstrained convex problem
$$\eqalign{
\min_x V(x) \cr
}$$

Comment: Agreeed this is a smart strategy. Im not sure if I see how it progress toward an answer on the particular question that has been asked?